# Compare 2 dictionary's and subtract the keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionary's with a int values as keys. I want to subtract the values from the dictionary's where the keys are the same.

Example:

```
dictA={'key1':3, 'key2':4, 'key3':9, 'key5':5}
dictB={'key1':2, 'key2':5, 'key3':5, 'key4':4}
```

Output what I want:

```
difference = {'key1':1,'key2':1,'key3':4,'key4':4,'key5':5}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> dictA={'key1':3, 'key2':4, 'key3':9, 'key5':5}
>>> dictB={'key1':2, 'key2':5, 'key3':5, 'key4':4}
>>> dict( (k, abs(dictA.get(k, 0) - dictB.get(k, 0))) for k in set(dictA.keys())|set(dictB.keys()))
{'key3': 4, 'key2': 1, 'key1': 1, 'key5': 5, 'key4': 4}
>>> _ == {'key1':1,'key2':1,'key3':4,'key4':4,'key5':5}
True
```

Exactly as requested. Tested with Python 2.7.3.